# NPM peer dependencies error with correct version of package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have an error on `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 does not satisfy its sibling
s' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.0.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
```

I don't understand what's wrong with rxjs version. `@angular/core@2.0.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12` But the rxjs version is already `5.0.0-beta.12`

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "nested-property": "0.0.7",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.0.7",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-datetime-picker": "^0.9.7",
    "ng2-redux": "^3.3.2",
    "ng2-redux-router": "^1.3.3",
    "ng2-toasty": "^2.1.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^3.1.2",
    "normalizr": "^2.2.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-actions": "^0.12.0",
    "redux-logger": "^2.7.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-hmr": "~0.8.1",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^1.2.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "ts-node": "^1.4.3",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
  }
}
```

Error on `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\dev\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\dev\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\
in\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 does not satisfy its siblin
s' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.0.0 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
```

Nodejs version v4.6.0 (includes npm 2.15.9)

Comment: have you tried deleting "node_modules" folder?

Comment: Yes, I execute npm install without node_modules directory. You can create an empty directory with package.json and you will get the same error.